# C# linq Closest point from a specific route

Tags: c#, linq, intersection

I would like to calculate all cities close to a specific route.

The idea is to create a bounding box between 2 coordinates points.

[image: Bounding box]

And query the database with linq to get all the cities inside this box.

[image: Database]

```
var polygon = DbGeography.PolygonFromText(@"POLYGON((145.2898592378906 -37.66376896413059,
                                                     145.2898592378906 -37.93504877166811, 
                                                     144.7075838472656 -37.93504877166811, 
                                                     144.7075838472656 -37.66376896413059, 
                                                     145.2898592378906 -37.66376896413059))", 
                                                     4326);

var CitiesQuery = db.Cities.Where(p => p.Position.Intersects(polygon));
```

How can i create the bounding box between the 2 points ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have two points: (x1, y1) and (x2, y2), then the corners of your bounding box are: (x1, y1), (x1, y2), (x2, y2), (x2, y1). This assumes you don't care about the order of the points of your bounding box.